# Any recommend José Mourinho biography book?

Tags: football

I'm interested in José Mourinho , currently Real Madrid C.F. Football Manager, and I would like to know more about him.
Is there a biography or any suggested reading on this guy?

Comment: You could always have a look at [his wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Mourinho).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Special One does have an authorised biography called [Jose Mourinho: Made in Portugal](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Jose-Mourinho-Portugal-Authorised-Biography/dp/0954684338)